# How to access the value of a variable from a javascript file in a jade file?

Tags: javascript, pug

I have created a variable in my js file called loginCount.

This is how I have defined it:

```
var loginCount = 0;
```

and this is how I am using it in this file:

```
function login(req, res) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    req.session.username = username;
    loggedInUsers[username] = LoggedIn;
    req.session.loginCount = loginCount;
    for (username in loggedInUsers){ 
        loginCount++;
        console.log("Login Count:", loginCount);
    }
    res.redirect("/users")
}
```

In my jade file I have tried

```
(#{loginCount} sessions)
```

but this doesn't work, it only shows ( sessions).  Any insight?

Thanks!

Comment: Too little information. I don't thinks that #{loginCount} will display the value of your variable, especially when you do some redirect. Where this variable should be stored? Please give some information about you more globally architecture, or maybe your project (is it so secure?)

Answer (score 2):

in calling the jade file try:-

```
res.redirect("/users", {login: loginCount } );
```

now you can refer to the variable in jade :-

```
#{loginCount} // this will type the value of the variable.
```